# Detect DataContext change in user control

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am implementing an `UserControl` and I want to detect if the DataContext is changed from the code. `FrameworkElement.DataContext.Get` is not virtual so I can't override it. I can hide it with `new` but I believe there is better way to do this. In WPF there is something like DataContextChanged event. Can we do something similar with Windows Phone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your user control constructor add this:

```
this.SetBinding(BoundDataContextProperty, new Binding());
```

Then add these:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundDataContextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "BoundDataContext",
    typeof(object),
    typeof(MyUserControl),
    new PropertyMetadata(null, OnBoundDataContextChanged));

private static void OnBoundDataContextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // e.NewValue is your new DataContext
    // d is your UserControl
}
```

Answer (score 1):

UserControl class has inner event UserControl_DataContextChanged to subscribe for that purpose

```
<UserControl 
         DataContextChanged="UserControl_DataContextChanged">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this [PropertyChangedNotifier](http://agsmith.wordpress.com/2008/04/07/propertydescriptor-addvaluechanged-alternative/)

Answer (score 0):

register to the frameworkelement.datacontextchanged event

you can find the answer here ,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontextchanged?view=net-5.0